# RejectChanges for specific Entities

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm having the following issue with WCF RIA Services: I have a table **Customer** and a table **Address**. A customer can have 0...n addresses. There is a form for editing the customer, with a Datagrid that displays the addresses. You add / edit an address in a child window by clicking *Add* / *Edit*. Now here's the thing:

The problem is that the user should always be able to cancel edits. This is not a problem **except**: If you *create* a new customer and you add an address to that customer, then want to edit the address but want to ***cancel*** that edit.

- You can't do RejectChanges to the context, because it would erase the address with the customer.
- You can't use seperate contexts because then you can't establish the foreign key relation.

How would you guys solve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entity implements IRevertibleChangeTracking to support this scenario. Since it's implemented explicitly, you'll have to cast it. The following code will work.

```
((IRevertibleChangeTracking)address).RejectChanges();
```

Comment: tiny misspelling in the interface name (IRevertibleChangeTracking) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.irevertiblechangetracking%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: How about with Related Property? I have

Answer (score 0):

It's working in case of edit but not in case of new..

Comment: In case of new you nust detatch the entity again.